# PIP install pandas not working

Tags: pandas

I am trying to install pandas with .whl file in a work computer but I get " cannot fetch URL" error. I have up to date version of PIP installed.How can I get this to work.I'm using Python 3.5.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't *describe* your error, copy and paste the entire error message -- and the command you used -- into your question.

Comment: this would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

Answer (score 0):

I just used the following which was quite simple. First open a console then cd to where you've downloaded your file like some-package.whl and use

```
pip install some-package.whl
```

`python -m pip install some-package.whl` also works if pip is not found in PATH

Note: if pip.exe is not recognized, you may find it in the "Scripts" directory from where python has been installed. If pip is not installed, this page can help:
[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

*Note: for clarification*
If you copy the `*.whl` file to your local drive (ex. **C:\some-dir\some-file.whl**) use the following command line parameters --

```
pip install C:/some-dir/some-file.whl
```

I guess since you are on a work computer
try this

```
sudo pip --proxy=http://username:password@proxyURL:portNumber install yolk
```

for example:
    `sudo pip --proxy=http://202.194.64.89:8000 install elasticsearch`

202.194.64.89:8000 is my PROXY,

Comment: So what is the Username:password for? Also how would I know what my Proxy is? Sorry not that smart to know all these.

Comment: @RajibMusyaju share us the snippet of your error and what you tried